Facebook Insights API - Can't Return Standard Events Besides Leads and Purchases
I have been able to successfully query the data in the API for Impressions, clicks, spend, leads, and purchases, but I have a couple standard events that I can't seem to find a way to return.  'schedule' is the primary one.
Is it possible to get other standard events to return through the Insights API?
Here is what I have tried to find it:
if (action.action_type.includes('appointment') || action.action_type.includes('schedule') || action.action_type === 'offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_schedule') {
appointmentsScheduled += parseInt(action.value);
A similar version for leads and purchases works just fine, but I can't access other standard events. it just returns zeros.
